# GNUPLOT error: When using arithmetic operation on one column of dat file in bash shell

Tags: bash, math, gnuplot

```
 #!/bin/bash

gnuplot -persist <<-EOFMarker

reset
set terminal svg enhanced size 500,500 
set output 'plot.svg'
set   autoscale                        # scale axes automatically
unset log                              # remove any log-scaling
      unset label                            # remove any previous labels
      set xtic auto                          # set xtics automatically
      set ytic auto                          # set ytics automatically

set ylabel "Loading (mmol/gm)"
set xlabel "Pressure (kPa)"
set key left top
set key autotitle columnhead
set grid

plot "all_isotherm_15.dat" using (($2)/100000):3 title 'Simulation273K' with linespoints , \
"all_isotherm_15.dat" using (($2)/100000):5 title 'Simulation298K' with linespoints 
EOFMarker
```

I am getting below error

```
gnuplot> plot "all_isotherm_15.dat" using (/100000):3 title 'Simulation273K' with linespoints , "all_isotherm_15" using (/100000):5 title 'Simulation298K' with linespoints 

       ^

 line 0: invalid expression
```

Comment: Use `column(2)` instead of `$2`

Answer (score 1):

You get the $2 interpreted by bash as strings. As they are not defined, they get replaced by nothing.

Why not directly use gnuplot as the interpreter of the shell script, i.e., start the file as

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist

reset
...
```